# can't load nib error message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am getting a very annoying error message:

'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'SingleStoryViewController''

Any idea why? That SingleStoryViewController nib is there available in the project.

I am not sure which code to post, but here's what I have:

```
if ([viewType isEqualToString:kSingleStoryView]){
                viewController = [[SingleStoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SingleStoryViewController" bundle:nil];
            }
```

Comment: If your using initWithNibName you might want to check the spelling and case of the string: @"SingleStoryViewController"

Comment: If there's nothing obvious in the spelling, choose your target, go to the Build Phases tab, and open the Copy Bundle Resources Section.  Make sure your xib file is there (or post a screen shot of what **is** there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is the name of the NIB exactly SingleStoryViewController.xib
2. Is it marked to be copied to the bundle
3. Is it in the Resources folder
4. Open the .app bundle -- is it there? In the Resources folder?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following points:

1) You have spelled the nib filename correctly.

2) You have specified "SingleStoryViewController" as the Parent class for the file's owner object in nib file.

3) You have connected the view outlet in the nib file to the UIView.

Please let us know if any query.